# How to run a task after another using taskGraph.whenReady closure

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to include a ZIP file inside a TAR file in a gradle build. I'm not insane, this is to replicate an existing ant script and I cannot change the distribution layout for various business reasons.

- I'm having to use a whenReady closure to [collect dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752078/multiproject-gradle-duplicate-dependencies-in-distribution-zip) without problems
- whenReady means that the ZIP file is not built until after the buildTar task has completed, even though buildTar depends on buildZip.
- I cannot call tar {} directly as gradle does not support this
- Gradle does not appear to support calling tasks directly.

This is the general layout I have

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
   gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
      // build zip file usual way with from blocks
      from(...) {
      }
      from(...) {
      }
   }
   doLast {
      println "ZIP ready"
      // could I call tar task from here??
   }
}

task buildTar(type: Tar, dependsOn: buildZip) {
    println "Building TAR"
    from (buildZip.archivePath) {
    }
    ... more stuff, installer script etc.
}
```

Output I see with gradle :buildTar, i.e. the TAR builds before the ZIP is built.

```
Building TAR
ZIP ready
```

Update.

Perryn Fowler comment below identifies the issue correctly, it is based on my misunderstanding of execution vs configuration in gradle.

> The Tar is not being built before the Zip, the Tar task is being
>   configured before the Zip task is executed

Update.

This question is no longer necessary as the option duplicatesStrategy can be used in the ZIP task to avoid the problem being 'fixed' with gradle.taskGraph.whenReady

Comment: The Tar is not being built before the Zip, the Tar task is being *configured* before the Zip task is executed. See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#build_lifecycle

Comment: @PerrynFowler Please could you add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question was actually provided by Perryn Fowler in the top comments, it was was based on my misunderstanding of execution vs configuration in gradle. I've created this answer so the question is marked as answered. The other answer simply paraphrases the original question with a link to the userguide.

> The Tar is not being built before the Zip, the Tar task is being
>   configured before the Zip task is executed

i.e. any nested commands within a special task, e.g. Zip, Tar etc. are run and configuration time, the from blocks are executed later.

Comment: The `from` isn't executed later unless `from { ... }` is used, which is a more accurate way to defer evaluation than `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { from ... }`.

Comment: yes, I agree completely in the general case. However if your 'from' is from (subprojects.configurations.compile) I found things are a little different.... subprojects.configurations.compile returns duplicates in a multiproject setup, and the only way to remove those duplicates is to call subprojects.configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration, however this must be down AFTER gradle.taskGraph.whenReady, if it is done BEFORE, i.e. without gradle.taskGraph.whenReady then subprojects fail to configure their dependencies blocks because they're already marked as resolved (changes to read-only).

Answer (score 1):

Here You have a sample working solution:

**build.gradle**:

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    from 'dir'
    destinationDir project.file('build/zip')
    archiveName 'lol.zip'
}

task buildTar(type: Tar, dependsOn: buildZip) {
    from 'build/zip'
    include '*.zip'
    destinationDir project.file('build/tar')
    archiveName 'lol.tar'
}
```

Is that clear for You?

P.S. I think that's a good idea for You to read [userguide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.html).

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use gradle.taskGraph.whenReady for reasons described in link in the original problem. I have read the userguide...

Comment: Ok then. Could You please prepare an SSCCE to try and understand the requirements well?

Comment: Instead of `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { from ... }`, `from { ... }` should be used. Anyway, this doesn't change anything fundamental. `buildTar` should use `from buildZip`, which also makes an explicit `dependsOn` unnecessary.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser gradle.taskGraph.whenReady is only necessary to solve problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752078/multiproject-gradle-duplicate-dependencies-in-distribution-zip if you have another solution to that let me know!

Comment: As I already said, `from { ... }` should be used instead (notice the curly braces).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752078/multiproject-gradle-duplicate-dependencies-in-distribution-zip and then provide a working example without gradle.taskGraph.whenReady

Comment: In the multi-project setup described in the question? please post it on that question and I'll accept as an answer, I don't like having to use gradle.taskGraph.whenReady